# (Hibernate, mysql) Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql, hibernate, foreign-keys, h2

I have an application which was running on H2 database and Hibernate is the ORM tool. Currently, I am changing this application to use mysql database instead of H2 database and while doing this I came to this issue when saving flagjp entity.

Here is the FlagJP entity that caused this issue.

```
@Entity
public class FlagJP extends BaseModelJP {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "IdOrGenerated")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "IdOrGenerated", strategy = "com.jp.menu.api.model.JPSequenceGenerator")
    private Long flagId;

    private String flagKey;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="flag", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<FlagLangJP> flagLangs = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne
    private FlagCategoryJP flagCategory;
```

Here are the related entities for the FlagJP

Second entity

```
@Entity
public class FlagLangJP extends BaseModelJP {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "IdOrGenerated")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "IdOrGenerated", strategy = "com.jp.menu.api.model.JPSequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    private String languageCode;

    private String flagName;

    private String flagDescription;

    @ManyToOne
    private FlagJP flag;
```

Third Entity

```
@Entity
public class FlagCategoryJP extends BaseModelJP {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "IdOrGenerated")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "IdOrGenerated", strategy = "com.jp.menu.api.model.JPSequenceGenerator")
    private Long flagCategoryId;

    private String flagCategoryName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "flagCategory")
    private List<FlagJP> flags;
```

While looking into this issue, I was able to figure out that this is cased by FlagJP table schema not having auto increment set in the database when hibernate generated the DDL.

here is the DDL of FlagJP

[image]

If I try to manually set the auto increment by executing a sql query, then mysql throw this error.

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1833: Cannot change column 'flagId': used in a foreign key constraint 'FK_sk95esyf1n0gt1qqmlmdmq0uw' of table 'butterfly_emenu.flaglangbpa'
SQL Statement:
```

my question is , this problem does not happen when using H2 database. how to solve this issue using hibernate when the database is mysql.

Thanks in advance for any advice

Update:

Here is the code for sequence generator I am using

```
public class JPSequenceGenerator extends IdentityGenerator {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JPSequenceGenerator.class);

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object) throws HibernateException {
        Serializable id = session.getEntityPersister(null, object).getClassMetadata().getIdentifier(object, session);

        if (id == null) {
            id = super.generate(session, object);

        }



        return id;
    }

}
```

Comment: This issue occurs, when the sequence generated id null or not storing in table properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code with auto_increment field ID in mysql

```
  @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long flagId;
```

If you are not able to add `auto_increment` for flagId then remove the foreignKey `FK_sk95esyf1n0gt1qqmlmdmq0uw` then add auto_increment and add foreign key again

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I did the change u suggested, but the issue still exists. Regarding your comment on removing FK and do the alteration to the table, I don't like this approach. I want the DDL to be generated based on hibernate entities and it should just work without any manual changes to database. How to get the hibernate work in this case

Comment: @KItis By specifying this `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` in Entity class and generate DDL via hibernate . Will it gives the same error?Have you tried